ECC with specific order - Proving cyclic or not
Given $E$ an elliptic curve defined in $\mathbb{Z}_q$ where $q>3$ and the cardinal $\#E=p_1p_2$ the product of two primes. Is $(E,+)$ cyclic?
I have begun with the conditions:
A cardinal group $p_1p_2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p_1}\times \mathbb{Z}_{p_2}$, so $p_1p_2$ must be prime to $q$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{p_1},\mathbb{Z}_{p_2}$ must be both cyclic.
Is there other conditions that we can prove with ?
I found this but I could not find any theorem that prove it:
If $E$ is not cyclic it will respect the form $\mathbb{Z}/d_1\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/d_2\mathbb{Z}$ such that $d_1$ divides $d_2$: $d_2=hd_1$. So $\#E=p_1p_2=d_1d_2=hd_1^2$ and $p_1p_2$ is divisible by a square, which is impossible. So $E$ is not cyclic.
Why they assume that $d_1$ divides $d_2$?


Given $E$ an elliptic curve defined in $\mathbb{Z}_q$ where $q>3$ and the cardinal $\#E=p_1p_2$ the product of two primes. Is $(E,+)$ cyclic?

If $p_1 \ne p_2$, then $E$ is necessarily cyclic.  In general, if the size of an elliptic curve group is square-free (that is, there is no integer $k > 1$ where $k^2$ divides the size of the group), then the group will be cyclic.

Why they assume that $d_1$ divides $d_2$?

They don't assume it; it's part of what's proven.
It turns out to be a consequence of a fairly fundamental theorem in group theory.  For any finite Abelian group $G$ (and all elliptic curves over a finite field are in this category), the group is isomorphic to:
$$G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{d_1} \times \mathbb{Z}_{d_2} \times .. \times \mathbb{Z}_{d_i}$$
for a unique sequence of integers $d_1, d_2, ..., d_i$ with $d_j | d_{j+1}$ for $1 \le j < i$ and $d_1 > 1$
Now, for an elliptic curve group, we have $i \in \{1, 2\}$ (and that's the nontrivial part that the theorem you specified proves - everything else is common to any Abelian group).  If $i = 1$, the group is cyclic, if $i=2$, the group is not (and in that case, we have $d_1$ dividing $d_2$, because that's what the general theorem says).
